# Open and plot multiple files

Tags: r

I have multiple files of this type (same number of columns, different rows)

```
A     1      1   1   43.50   12.50   
A     1      1   5   44.50   12.50   
A     1      1   9   44.50   12.50   
A     1      1   13      45.50   12.50   
A     1      1   17      45.50   12.50  
A     1      1   21      46.50   12.50   
A     1      2   1   47.50   12.50   
A     1      2   5   47.50   12.50   
A     1      2   9   48.50   12.50
```

I would like to open all those files and plot for every one the last two columns. I managed to open them using `lapply`

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.dat")
myfilesContent <- lapply(myfiles, read.table, header=T, sep = "\t")
```

but then I am stack..

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you plan to do with the plots? Show them one by one? Save all into a single pdf-file? Output them to individual files? How would you plot the data from just a single file?

Comment: So now you have a list of dataframes in `myfilesContent`. You can access the first one with `myfilesContent[[0]]`. Once you can create a plot from one of the dataframes, then all you need do is apply that plotting function to your list via a looping function.

Comment: I meant `myfilesContent[[1]]`. List indices in R start at 1 rather than 0. Sorry if my error confused anyone.

Comment: I would like to show them one by one..

Comment: To followup on @dnagirl 's comments: each `myfilesContent[[j]]` has the entire array, so you'd loop over `j`, calling `plot(myfilesContent[[j]][,5],myfilesContent[[j]][,6],...)`

Comment: Could you post the code you are using to plot one dataset, please?

Answer (score 3):

You have already used lapply once - why not using it twice?

Reading your description, I guess you are unsure about the size of your data.frames and thusly need to identify the last two columns, that are to be plotted, automatically and hand them to your plot-function.

I would use the following solution:

```
> myfiles <- lapply(list.files(pattern = "*.dat"),
+   read.table, header = TRUE, sep = "\t"
+ )

> # No check whether dim() will work correctly with your data!
> listplot <- function(x) {
>   col1 <- dim(x)[2] - 1
>   col2 <- dim(x)[2]
>   plot(x[,col1], x[,col2], type = "p")
> }

> lapply(myfiles, listplot)
```

This will do all the plots in one go; further arguments to `plot` as well as any other stuff such as saving the images would go into the listplot function.